# Google Datastore: query filter by descendant key

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

In google datastore, is it possible to query for keys that do *not* contain a specific child.

So, if I have the following data

```
<User>/<Action=Purchase>/<Id=123456>/Initiate
                                    /Complete
```

I would like to find all purchases that are not complete - ie, that do not contain a 'Complete' child.

I would also like all changes to be non-destructive - ie, I want to avoid ovewritting any existing data.  So for example, I would prefer to avoid having a parameter on Id=123456 that records state (does that make sense, or is it a silly requirement?)

(I am creating this in node, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Cloud Datastore to query for missing data.  You can only query for data that exists.  So you'll need to track a state, probably on your id=123456 entity.

Comment: Thats what I suspected.  Thanks for the confirmation